# How Do I Create A Page Scroller Like In Apple's iBooks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ibooks

[image]

You guys get what I mean. I have no idea how to do this. There are no tutorials anywhere and so far I've spent about 4 hours on this to no avail. Can anyone point me to anything useful or give me a quick run down on how I would achieve this? Cheers.

Comment: That looks like Pages, not iBooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: create a `UIView` or `UIControl` subclass. Draw thumbnail images of the pages. Respond to touch events and send selection changes to a delegate that can then update the real page. Something like that :-)